# Gradle/Android SDK problems importing cloned project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I'm attempting to start development on a new computer, so I downloaded eclipse mars and installed the adt plugin, android sdks, and gradle plugin. I then cloned my libGDX (uses gradle) project and tried to import it using the gradle plugin, which results in this: 
[image]

So I tried setting ANDROID_HOME to my sdk path, like so: 
[image]

After this, I still get the same error, so I tried making a local.properties file as "sdk.dir=C:\Users\quant_000\android-sdks", and this gives me a different error on import:
[image]

I also tried it with the local.properties file, but without the environment variable, and that still gives me the above error. I have no idea why this is happening, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd, but the problem seemed to solve itself. I left my computer alone for half a day, came back and no longer have the "already created sdk loader" problems, replaced with "missing build tools revision 20.0.0." I then used the SDK manager to install this build tools version, but importing still didn't work, until I saw there were two gradle import options and tried the other one (not even sure why I have two). This answer is probably going to be useless, so I apologize in advance.